# Rails distinct values of a value returned by a method in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose I have an Employee model, there is a method in Employee model named def fixed

```
  def fixed
    return self.cached_fixed.to_f if self.cached_fixed.present?

    return (self.current_salary && self.current_salary.fixed).to_f
  end
end
```

```
def current_salary
    return @current_salary if @current_salary
    # @current_salary = self.employee_salaries.detect{|es| es.end_date == nil}
    @current_salary = self.db_current_salary
    return @current_salary
end
```

if the fixed were a column in employee table we could have just used Employee.distinct.select(:fixed) to pull the distinct values

is there a way if it's just a method not a field in table without loading all the employees.

I am expecting to get the unique values of a column from a table , but it may not be a column as in the above table

Answer (score 0):

Not for an arbitrary method, no. But you start the query from the `EmployeeSalary` end and fetch only the column you care about in one query using [select](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields):

```
EmployeeSalary
  .select(:fixed) 
  .join(:employee)
  .where(end_date: nil)
```

This will run a `select fixed from...` query and return a list of EmployeeSalary objects, but all the fields that aren't listed in the `select` call will be nil. Assuming the constraint of only one salary record having `end_date: nil`, there will be one EmployeeSalary object per employee. You can add `.distinct` in the method chain if you want unique values.

I'm not sure how the caching logic fits into this question. You can apply caching logic on top of that list if you like, but doing one query like this is pretty fast.